# Winform object has event subscriptions deleted when modifying layout

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

So I added a BackGroundWorker object to my `FormMain.cs` and created two methods to handle the events `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`. I found that I had to go into `ForMain.Designer.cs` to manually wire up the methods to the events ..

```
this.bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
this.bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
this.bgWorker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.bgWorker_DoWork);
this.bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
this.bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

The confusing thing is if I alter any of the controls at all on the `FormMain.Designer.cs` then the two event **wire-ups** I created are deleted and I have to manually add them back. This includes moving controls around on the designer. Any idea why this would happen?

These have to be added back manually

```
this.bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
this.bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer file is meant to be used by the designer only - it will be ripped up and re-written as you make changes in the designer.  There's usually this comment above `InitializeComponent`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
```

Note it says **do not modify the contents with the code editor**. You should either add these event handlers via the designer UI, or you should add them in the code behind file (the other half of the `partial` class).

For example, add them in the constructor after `InitializeComponent` has been called:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
        this.bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
}
```